# How can I make the whole form go up when the keyboard appears?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a registration screen with the form at the bottom of the screen, and I want to make it so that the whole form goes up when any `TextField` is tapped, for some reason only the very last one does that. However, I am also faced with another problem. My UI kind of swallows up the form that goes up. I want the white part to expand along with the form so that it takes up the whole screen basically.

#### Code:

```
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        //resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        backgroundColor: backGroundPink,
        // backgroundColor: whiteColor,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                const SizedBox(height: 45.0),
                Container(
                  height: 100,
                  child: Text(
                    "Get Started",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xFFD77D7C),
                      fontSize: 38,
                      fontFamily: 'Urbanist',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      height: 1.30,
                      letterSpacing: -0.28,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                // const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 22.0,
                      right: 22,
                      top: 5.0,
                      bottom: 5,
                    ),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                          top: Radius.circular(80.0) //change this,
                          ),
                    ),
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      /* padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          bottom:
                              MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 100),*/
                      // physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      child: Column(
                        //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          const SizedBox(height: 40.0),
                          Text("Create a Preggo account",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 23.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              )),
                          const SizedBox(height: 45.0),
                          /*const SizedBox(height: 40.0),
                          Text("Welcome back!",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 23.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              )),
                              */
                          //  const SizedBox(height: 50.0),
                          Container(
                            height: 85,
                            constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 100),
                            child: TextFormField(
                              controller: _usernameController,
                              key: _usernameKey,
                              validator: (value) {
                                /*
                                      username validations:
                                      --FRONT END--
                                      1- not empty
                                      2- no spaces
                                      3- no special characters (only letters and digits)
                                      --BACK END--
                                      4- unique
                                      */

                                if (value!.isEmpty == true) {
                                  return "This field cannot be empty.";
                                } else if (!validCharacters.hasMatch(value)) {
                                  return "Only alphanumerical values allowed."; //maybe change error message
                                } else if (usernameTaken) {
                                  return 'Username is already taken!';
                                } else {
                                  return null;
                                }
                              },
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                hintText: "Username",
                                helperText: '',
                                labelStyle: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 15,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                  color: grayColor,
                                ),
                                prefixIcon: const Icon(
                                  Icons.person,
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                ),
                                filled: true,
                                fillColor: textFieldBackgroundColor,
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                                ),
                                enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                                  borderSide:
                                      BorderSide(color: textFieldBorderColor),
                                ),
                                focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: darkGrayColor),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),

                          // const SizedBox(height: 22.0),
                          Container(
                            height: 85,
                            constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 100),
                            child: TextFormField(
                              controller: _emailController,
                              key: _emailKey,
                              validator: (value) {
                                if (value!.isEmpty) {
                                  return "This field cannot be empty.";
                                } else if (!EmailValidator.validate(value)) {
                                  return "Please enter a valid email.";
                                } else if (emailTaken) {
                                  return 'Email is already taken!';
                                } else {
                                  return null;
                                }
                              },
                              /*
                                      email validations:
                                      --FRONT END--
                                      1- format: xxx@xxx.xxx
                                      2- only allowed characters of email
                                      3- only 1 @
                                      4- not empty
                                      --BACK END--
                                      5- unique
                                      */
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                helperText: '',
                                hintText: "Email",
                                labelStyle: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 15,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                  color: grayColor,
                                ),
                                prefixIcon: const Icon(
                                  Icons.email,
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                ),
                                filled: true,
                                fillColor: textFieldBackgroundColor,
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                                ),
                                enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                                  borderSide:
                                      BorderSide(color: textFieldBorderColor),
                                ),
                                focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: darkGrayColor),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),

                          Container(
                            height: 85,
                            constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 100),
                            child: PhoneFormField(
                              countrySelectorNavigator:
                                  const CountrySelectorNavigator
                                      .searchDelegate(),
                              autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.disabled,
                              controller: _phoneControllerCC,
                              key: _phoneKey,

                              /*
                                      phone number validations
                                      --FRONT END--
                                      1- 10 digits
                                      2- digits only
                                      --BACK END--
                                      3- unique (???)
                                      */
                              validator: PhoneValidator.validMobile(),
                              /* (phone) {
                                  bool hasLetter = false;
                                  int i = 0;
                                  while (i < phone!.toString().length) {
                                    if (!isNumeric(phone.toString().[i])) {
                                      hasLetter = true;
                                    }
                                    i++;
                                  }
                                  if (hasLetter) {
                                    return 'Field must contain only digits.';
                                  }
                                  if (phone.toString().isEmpty) {
                                    return 'This field cannot be empty.';
                                  } else if (phone.toString().length != 10) {
                                    return 'Phone number must be 10 digits.';
                                  } else if (phoneTaken) { !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                                    return 'Phone number is already taken!';
                                  } else {
                                    return null;
                                  }
                                },*/
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                helperText: '',
                                hintText: "Phone number (optional)",
                                labelStyle: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 15,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                  color: grayColor,
                                ),
                                /*  prefixIcon: const Icon(
                                  Icons.phone,
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                ),*/
                                filled: true,
                                fillColor: textFieldBackgroundColor,
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                                ),
                                enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                                  borderSide:
                                      BorderSide(color: textFieldBorderColor),
                                ),
                                focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: darkGrayColor),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),

                          Container(
                            height: 85,
                            constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 90),
                            child: TextFormField(
                              controller: _passwordController,
                              /*
                                    password validations
                                    1- 8 digits or more
                                    2- at least one capital
                                    3- at least one number
                                    */

                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                helperText: '',
                                prefixIcon: const Icon(
                                  Icons.lock,
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                ),
                                hintText: 'Password',
                                labelStyle: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 15,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                  color: grayColor,
                                ),
                                filled: true,
                                fillColor: textFieldBackgroundColor,
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                                ),
                                enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                                  borderSide:
                                      BorderSide(color: textFieldBorderColor),
                                ),
                                focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: darkGrayColor),
                                ),
                                suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      hidePassword = !hidePassword;
                                    });
                                  },
                                  child: hidePassword
                                      ? const Icon(
                                          Icons.visibility_off,
                                          color: Colors.grey,
                                        )
                                      : const Icon(
                                          Icons.visibility,
                                          color: Colors.grey,
                                        ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              obscureText: hidePassword ? true : false,
                              autocorrect: false,
                              validator: (pass) {
                                if (pass!.isEmpty == true) {
                                  return "This field cannot be empty.";
                                } else if (pass.length < 8) {
                                  return "Password must be at least 8 characters.";
                                } else {
                                  bool hasDigit = false;
                                  bool hasUppercase = false;
                                  int i = 0;
                                  while (i < pass.length) {
                                    if (isNumeric(pass[i])) {
                                      hasDigit = true;
                                    } else if (isUppercase(pass[i])) {
                                      hasUppercase = true;
                                    }
                                    i++;
                                  } //end while
                                  if (hasDigit == false ||
                                      hasUppercase == false) {
                                    return "Password must contain at least one uppercase letter \nand one digit.";
                                  }
                                } //end else
                                return null;
                              },
                            ),
                          ),

                          //const SizedBox(height: 45.0),
                          MaterialButton(
                            color: darkBlackColor,
                            minWidth: double.infinity,
                            height: 48,
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
                            ),
                            onPressed: () 
 { },
                                child: Text(
                                  'Sign Up',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 15,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                    color: whiteColor,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(height: 25.0),
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    'Already have an account?  ',
                                    style: Theme.of(context)
                                        .textTheme
                                        .titleLarge
                                        ?.copyWith(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                          fontSize: 15,
                                          color: blackColor,
                                        ),
                                  ),
                                  GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                                          MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) {
                                          return const LoginScreen();
                                        },
                                      ), (route) => false);
                                    },
                                    child: Text(
                                      'Log In',
                                      style: Theme.of(context)
                                          .textTheme
                                          .titleLarge
                                          ?.copyWith(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                            fontSize: 15,
                                            color: pinkColor,
                                            decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                          ),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

#### Screenshots:

1. Regular UI
2. UI with the keyboard pulled up, covering the bottom fields and not **expanding** the white part
3. The white part **swallowing** the fields while scrolling the fields

| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: my regular ui] | [image: my UI with the keyboard pulled up, covering the bottom fields and not expanding the white part] | [image: the white part 'swallowing' the fields while scrolling the fields] |

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` property to `false`

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all change the `Expanded` widget to the `Flexible` widget (for flexibility)
2. Then wrap the first `Column` widget with `SingleChildScrollView` instead of wrapping the `Flexible` widget and add the `reverse: true` property to `SingleChildScrollView`
3. Add `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` to `Column`
4. Add `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true` to `Scaffold`

#### Screenshot of the code:

[image: code]

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to achieve it using `Flexible` widget instead of `Expanded`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).